# Column drag and drop without click the column chooser in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want drag and drop column for reorder in jqGrid.

I saw this <kbd>[Reference page](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser1.htm)</kbd>- that's good, but i want drag and drop the column in page only without click the column chooser button to drag and drop or rearrange.

```
jQuery("#colch").jqGrid({
    url: 'server.php?q=2',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'id',
        index: 'id',
        width: 55
    }, {
        name: 'invdate',
        index: 'invdate',
        width: 90
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        index: 'name asc, invdate',
        width: 100
    }, {
        name: 'amount',
        index: 'amount',
        width: 80,
        align: "right"
    }, {
        name: 'tax',
        index: 'tax',
        width: 80,
        align: "right"
    }, {
        name: 'total',
        index: 'total',
        width: 80,
        align: "right"
    }, {
        name: 'note',
        index: 'note',
        width: 150,
        sortable: false,
        hidden: true
    }],
    rowNum: 10,
    width: 700,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    pager: '#pcolch',
    sortname: 'invdate',
    shrinkToFit: false,
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "Column Chooser Example"
});
jQuery("#colch").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pcolch', {
    add: false,
    edit: false,
    del: false,
    search: false,
    refresh: false
});
jQuery("#colch").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pcolch', {
    caption: "Columns",
    title: "Reorder Columns",
    onClickButton: function() {
        jQuery("#colch").jqGrid('columnChooser');
    }
});
```

Any Suggestions are Appreciated.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `sortable: true` [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) of jqGrid. You need additionally include jQuery UI JavaScript file (not only CSS).

By the way `columnChooser` allows not only change the order of columns, but to hide/show columns mostly.